# Find home network in Android

Tags: android, gsm, telephony

I am working on Android Netwok selection.
I am getting information by searching networks as

```
OperatorInfo Vodafone IN/Vodafone IN/40420/AVAILABLE
 OperatorInfo BPL MOBILE/BPL MOBILE/40421/AVAILABLE
 OperatorInfo IDEA/IDEA/405799/FORBIDDEN
 OperatorInfo Aircel/Aircel/405805/FORBIDDEN
 OperatorInfo Reliance/Reliance/40515/AVAILABLE
 OperatorInfo IND airtel/airtel/40492/FORBIDDEN
 OperatorInfo TATA DOCOMO/TATA DO/405039/FORBIDDEN
 OperatorInfo IN-DOLPHIN/DOLPHIN/40469/AVAILABLE
```

I want to  find out which is Home-PLMN from these networks i.e. home network of the SIM currently present in the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try the TelephonyManager's [GetSimOperator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimOperator%28%29) method.